# AngularJS: Preselecting multiple options in listbox

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

My markup looks like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="7" 
     ng-model="model.SelectedCars" 
     ng-options="car.Code as car.Name for car in model.Cars track by car.Code">
</select>
```

I have initialized my scope with the following:

```
$scope.model.SelectedCars = [];
$scope.model.Cars = [
{Name: 'Car 1', Code: 'id01'},
{Name: 'Car 2', Code: 'id02'},
{Name: 'Car 3', Code: 'id03'}
];
```

This all works the way I want it to (Car name is displayed in listbox, Code is used as value). When I select something from the listbox (even multiple values), the `$scope.model.SelectedCars` array ends up populated with the Codes for each selected car(1d array of strings).

My question is, why if I manually push valid Codes into the `$scope.model.SelectedCars` array, is it not being reflected in the UI control as selected. This only happens when using `ng-options` or `ng-repeat`, seems like if I hard code the options to the  it does work.

The server will only provide my selected cars model as a 1d array of Codes (strings). I would much rather keep the data structure for the ng-model as is so I can send it up without any alterations prior to posting.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did it update after `$scope.$apply()` ?

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564)

That being said if you remove `track by` from *ngOptions* you can add a `model.Cars.code` to the list of `model.selectedCars` and the two way binding will work.

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="7" 
    ng-model="model.SelectedCars" 
    ng-options="car.Code as car.Name for car in model.Cars"></select>
```